# Transferring Millions of rows from teradata to mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, bigdata, teradata

I have to transfer around 5 million rows of data from Teradata to MySQL. Can anyone please suggest me the fastest way to do this over the network, without using the filesystem. I am new to Teradata and MySQL. I want to run this transfer as a batch job on weekly basis, so I am looking for the solution which can be fully automated. Any suggestions or hints will be greatly appreciated.

I have already written the code using JDBC to get the records from the Teradata and insert them into the MySQL. But it is very slow, so I am looking to make that code more efficient. I kept in generic because I didn't have the solution to be constrained by my implementation, as along with making existing code more efficient I am open to other alternatives also. But I don't want to use the file system since it's not easier to maintain or update the scripts.

My implementation:

**Getting records from teradata:**

```
connection  =   DBConnectionFactory.getDBConnection(SOURCE_DB);

    statement = connection.createStatement();
    rs = statement.executeQuery(QUERY_SELECT);
    while (rs.next()) {

        Offer offer = new Offer();
        offer.setExternalSourceId(rs.getString("EXT_SOURCE_ID"));
        offer.setClientOfferId(rs.getString("CLIENT_OFFER_ID"));
        offer.setUpcId(rs.getString("UPC_ID"));

        offers.add(offer);
    }
```

**Inserting the records in mySQL:**

```
int count = 0;
    if (isUpdated) {
        for (Offer offer : offers) {

            count++;

            stringBuilderUpdate = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilderUpdate = stringBuilderUpdate
                    .append(QUERY_INSERT);

            stringBuilderUpdate = stringBuilderUpdate.append("'"
                    + offer.getExternalSourceId() + "'");

            statement.addBatch(stringBuilderUpdate.toString());

            queryBuilder = queryBuilder.append(stringBuilderUpdate
                    .toString() + SEMI_COLON);

            if (count > LIMIT) {
                countUpdate = statement.executeBatch();
                LOG.info("DB update count : " + countUpdate.length);
                count = 0;
            }

        }
        if (count > 0) {
            // Execute batch
            countUpdate = statement.executeBatch();
        }
```

Can anybody please tell me if we can make this code more efficient ???

Thanks

PS: Please ignore the syntax error in above code as this code is working fine. Some info might be missing because of copy and paste.

Comment: how you finally did this task?

Answer (score 1):

The [**fastest**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html) method of importing data to MySQL is by using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) or [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html), which is a command line interface to `LOAD DATA INFILE` and it involves loading data from a file, preferably residing on a local filesystem.

> When loading a table from a text file, use LOAD DATA INFILE. This is
>   usually **20 times faster** than using INSERT statements.

Therefore despite the fact that you don't want to use the filesystem I'd suggest to consider creating a dump to a file, transfer it to a MySQL server and use above mentioned means to load the data.

All these tasks can be fully automated via scripting.

Comment: Also when adding large amounts of data to a table it can be quicker to drop all the index(es). Do the bulk insert and then recreate the index(es). This is likely to be more true where the data inserted is > 50% of the total data.