# Migrating from Teradata to MySQL with MySql Workbench is not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, teradata, database-migration

I have tried to migrate a Teradata datbase to MySQL using MySQL Workbench but teradata schema is not loading in mySql workbench migration wizard.

Teradata option was not there in the migration wizard in mysql workbench.  But there is an option Generic RDBMS then I have tried with the option yet I had no luck and schemas which are available in teradata are not getting loaded.

Is it possible to migrate from Teradata from MySQL?  or should I use some other tool to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transferring Millions of rows from teradata to mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414241/transferring-millions-of-rows-from-teradata-to-mysql)

Comment: I dont want it using code.  Is there any tool which helps